# How to export the output of multiple gcloud queries into adjacent sheets within one CSV file, using Bash?

Tags: bash, csv, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have the following 3 gcloud queries:

Query 1 - To enumerate users of a project:
`gcloud projects get-iam-policy MyProject --format="csv(bindings.members)" >> output1.csv`

Query 2 - To enumerate users of a folder:
`gcloud resource-manager folders get-iam-policy MyFolder --format="csv(bindings.members)" >> output2.csv`

Query 3 - To enumerate users of the organization:
`gcloud organizations get-iam-policy MyOrg --format="csv(bindings.members)" >> output3.csv`

My goal is to run all 3 queries together and export the output in multiple adjacent sheets within one CSV file, instead of 3 separate CSV files. Is that possible?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: What is an adjacent sheet of a CSV file? Maybe you talk about XLS files?

Comment: There can be multiple sheets within a CSV / XLS file, right? I need the output of the above 3 queries in three sheets but within the same CSV / XLS file.

Comment: CSV is not XLS. XLS does have sheets. CSV does not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

comma-delimited files (CSVs) do not support multiple 'tables' within a single file.

You must create a file per table.

Comment: Understood, thanks.